# Display ajax preloader for large images within posts

Tags: images, ajax, css, html

Our WordPress installation runs only images within posts. Generally medium, lightweight images but we are also publishing larger images, sometimes gif animations which take enormous time to load.

When a post has a description it is a bit different. The visitor has something to read and then the images pops out when loaded but that's not our case. As I said, we only display images within our posts.

When a post contains a big image, it is simply empty until the image is loaded, and I believe we are loosing a lot of possible future regular visitors because of this. They could believe we have empty pages.

My solution would be to display a tiny (ajax?) preloader until the image is loaded, so the visitor is notified that some content is being loaded. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you said one option is to place a preloader while the image is loading.

If you cannot touch so deep with JavaScript and PHP I have one simple sugestion which I think will work for you.

```
<div class="image-preloader">
   <img src="yourimage.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Create a wrapper (holder) around your image.
With CSS put the preloader as a background on the HOLDER DIV.

```
.image-preloader {
  background('images/loader.gif') 50% 50%;
}
```

Like that while the image is loading you will have your preloader and when the Image is loaded it will be hidden under it.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Simple and clean. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can check here a lot of JQ plugins to do that.

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/preload-image-plugins/

For example, this one:

http://nick-jonas.github.io/imageloader/